# HTML page loading time?

Tags: jquery, html

Does including jQuery functions with those `#id` or `.class` which are not present in the HTML code effect the loading time of the webpage?

For eg :-

```
$(function (){
    $("#id1").click(function(){

//something

});
```

There exist a function for `id1`, but there doesnt exist any tag with `id = id1`. Does this effect the loading time of the page?

Actually, I wanted to add my own widgets to my page, thereby letting the user customize his/her dashboard by placing/adding the widgets. I thought of a solution of adding  for the widgets dynamically by letting the user select the widgets from the list of widgets. After selecting the widgets, it will dynamically add divs for those widgets via `$( "#container" ).append( "<div id='id1'></div>" );` and thereby loading their respective jQuery functions. Will keeping the functions for those ids or classes in the js file optimized ? Is it the correct way of loading jQuery functions or is there something better?Just wanted to know is it the correct way of implementing widgets?

Comment: Yes, it will. Browser will have to parse your code.</sarcasm> Effects will be tiny.

Comment: In your code, the document is already loaded. Browser just runs your script.

Comment: @undefined- No what? Kindly elaborate

Comment: @ArtyomNeustroev- So, you mean to say that it will effect the loading time of the page?

Comment: @user1162512 no, it won't. The page is _already loaded_ when your event binding occurs since you wrapped it in `$(function () {})`.

Comment: @mishik - Is there any better way of doing it?

Comment: @user1162512 better way is to remove the code you're not using from production. Dev is ok, if needed.

Comment: Hey guys I've edited my question a bit. Apologize for being less informative at the initial phase.

Answer (score 1):

I would say load jquery from google CDN this will substantially reduce loading of jquery library. In terms of the function call, yes it does increase page loading time. But not by causing network delay. The function call you want to do after the page has been loaded so that id=id1 already exists. The function call setup will not increase page load time to a noticeable extent and do as many as you like. As your page becomes more javascript heavy then you'll want to consider optimizing it for run-time speed.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I actually wanted to add my own widgets to my page, thereby letting the user customize his/her dashboard by placing/adding the widgets.
I thought of a solution of adding `<div>` for the widgets dynamically by letting the user select the widgets from the list of widgets. After selecting the widgets, it will dynamically add divs for those widgets and thereby loading their respective jQuery functions. Just wanted to know is it the correct way of implementing widgets?
Thanks

Comment: I wouldn't say there is a correct way of implementing widgets. What you say sounds alright. And the paradigm where you load the code only when the widget is requested is called "lazy loading".

Answer (score 1):

No, this really doesn't affect the page-load time, the query fails and no handler is attached. If you are developing a Single Page Application then the thing that is important is performance of your application, if the application works slowly only then you should be worried about the performance.

http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization

If your application heavily uses JavaScript then you can consider using a library like [`RequireJS`](http://requirejs.org/) that is a module loader that can load the assets dynamically and improves the speed and quality of your code. RequireJS also has an [optimization tool](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html) than can be used for combining the related scripts together into build layers and minifing them via UglifyJS or Google Closure Compiler(requires Java) after development.

Comment: I request you to please again have a look at my edited question and respond accordingly. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If in jour *.js file you use:

```
$(function() {
//your jQuery code here
});
```

and if you load your external *.js file at the end of the document right before the tag `</body>` and only after you already loaded jQuery from Google CDN than the script will be executed only after the page loads completely.

By running your code in this way, if jQuery find no element with the specified id will do nothing. It will be affected the memory consumed by the browser of the user when parsing the DOM and searching after a possible element with the id you specified. That's all.

A correct way to work with jQuery is by loading and executing the jQuery code as I described you above.

One thought; when you append to the DOM elements, do it before searching for that elements:

```
$(function() {
$( "#container" ).append( "<div id='id1'></div>" );
$('#id1').append('some HTML content');
});
```